# CLLocationManager bad quality at navigation when vehicle vibrates

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cllocation

I got some customer feedback of our navigation app. It seems like the app's GPS system is not working as expected when having the iphone/ipad clamped into a holder, connected directly with the vehicle. The signal went pretty bad. It might have a problem with the vibrations, is there any workaround for such a use case? Vibrations cannot be avoided, but maybe there is a flag I can set to the CLLocationManager?

First researches: Setting the activityType .airborne might help, but doesn't this have any other side effects to the navigation quality?

Best
Chris

Comment: I don't think vibrations would have any impact on gps. Gps has an accuracy of around 10m. Vibrations are going to move the phone by a few mm at most. Gps signals are very low power.  They are affected by metal and concrete. There are also susceptible to reflections in streets surrounded by tall buildings. This will cause it to appear that the device is moving when it is stationary or for it jump around as the gps tries to work out where it is. You could have your code monitor the `horizontalAccuracy` and display a warning icon if accuracy drops.